# Access Internet through another computer connected to wireless Internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I have two computers connected via LAN that works well. The first one is connected to the Internet via WiFi.

How can I connect the second PC to the Internet?

Both computers have Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

on the internet pc: open network connections -> right mouse button on your wifi connection -> preferences -> sharing tab -> check first tick box.

on the second pc, add first pc's IP address as default gateway on your lan connection.

(when completing the first step, your first PC's IP address will change, so be sure to use the new one as the default gateway)

Comment: I've tried to do that but could not happen. the sharing was not because should set an IP address 192.168.137.1 to the Lan adapter. Then got an error message that could not happen. What should I do?

Comment: I hope to get an answer